# Huawei AppGallery rejected my application draft because of connectivity issues

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

My application "ADO - Boletos de Autobus" was rejected with the following comments:

> 1. [Description]: We found that your App is abnormal, which prompts "Uy! Algo paso, por favor intenta mas tarde" during the registration process. Please see the attachment. Please refer to the rule 3.4 of "AppGallery Review Guidelines": https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/30202 [Suggestion]: Please revise it accordingly.
> 2. [Description]: An error occurs in your App. Please see the attachment. Please refer to the rule 3.1 of "AppGallery Review Guidelines": https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/30202
>
> [Test Step]: When clicking [Terminales - Buscar terminal - "Select any one"] The application does not show any results.
>
> [Test Environment]: Wi-Fi networking, Android 9.0/EMUI 9.1.0 (P30), Android 10, EMUI 10.0.0 (Mate 30 Pro), Multilingual settings. [Suggestion]: Please identify it accordingly. Then revise and resubmit your App for review.

I presume this is happening because our web service API is not reachable from China because of some third-party firewall configuration in the place where the web services are located.
Have you guys had any previous experience with this? Can we be in touch to treat this topic directly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please leave your appId? Let me check the info to see the problem.

Comment: @shirley here is my App ID: 102718291

Comment: We have retested the app and found that an error occurred when using the app outside China. It is not an firewall configuration issue. Besides, your AppGallery Review is also outside China. If you find anything else, feel free to contact me. @Jorge Gil

Comment: Hi @shirley, we have been testing the application regarding the two points where the Huawei team found errors, and we figured out that they were occurring due to the following: 1. There was an intermittence in the backend side. Afterward, we were able to register a user.  2. It was because our Google Cloud Platform was downgraded for a few days because it was not paid on time... can you guys help us to re-test the same application already submitted or should we submit a new version? Thank you!

Comment: You should submit a new version and then we can check the info!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app was retested according to the provided appid, and it was found your app was not reviewed in China. Therefore, the rejection is irrelevant to the firewall configuration issue.

According to [AppGallery Review Guidelines](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/30202#h1-3-app-function?ha_source=hms1) 3.1 and 3.4, the app was rejected due to function issues. The primary functional reason includes the following three parts:

1. Unable to install or uninstall, frequent errors, and failures during testing
2. The major function is not realized
3. Low compatibility (firmware/model/screen, etc.)

If you do not understand the rejection comments, contact the AppGallery review team to obtain details and how to modify it. Then submit it for review again.